# Parsing python doesn't work when encapsulated

Tags: python-2.7, xml-parsing, automation, python-requests

I'm parsing a xml file (recurring task) with python 2.7 and xml.etree.
Getting the data using requests.

Everything works, but I put my script in sub routines, then it fails:

```
File "<string>", line unknown
ParseError: no element found: line 1, column 0
```

This is the complete error message and it makes no sense to me. Same error if I put everything in main(), without any other fucntion.

The only workaround is to remove any sort of function. Yet I have to loop many times every morning, which is not optimal.

Any idea? Cheers
Vincent

EDIT1:
Here is a piece of the code I'm executing

```
response=requests.post(url,data=body.replace('\n',''),headers=headers)
tree = ET.fromstring(response.content)
ticket=tree.find('.//{http://services.zanox.com/erp}ticket').text
```

Then I just use the ticket var in another string that will be used for the new "body", and it just goes like that. But even this simple task return the aforementioned error.

Comment: It's hard to pinpoint the error with no code shown, can't reproduce the error. Maybe it's the way you call the function or even how you delare it.

Comment: @RafaelAlmeida : I wanted to but I'm connecting to an API and sadly without the first call you cannot authentificate and therefore use the code... I guess. Otherwise than that, the code is really simple; I'm putting an exmaple in the post. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally found it: it was because of IPython.
Works as expected with the python shell.